# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/3766-6230/MyData/smallv.mp4 (Permission denied)

Tags: android, permissions, android-external-storage

Even though the permisson test for the external storage returns granted,
FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel();  throws an exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/3766-6230/MyData/smallv.mp4 (Permission denied)

the path "/storage/3766-6230/MyData/" exists and I can move/copy files to this directory
using file manager app with no issues. Unable to figure out what is missing in the code below.
Note: the hardcoded paths in the code given to make it simple, these are picked by the
user by browsing the directories in the app.

```
  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(v.getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     // Permission is already available, write to the file.
     File filetocopy = new File("/sdcard/tmp", "test.mp4");
     File newFile = new File("/storage/3766-6230/MyData", "test.mp4");
     if (newFile.exists()) return -1;    // file with the given name already exists
     try {
        inputChannel = new FileInputStream(filetocopy).getChannel();
        outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel();  // This throws exception
        copyFile(inputChannel, outputChannel );
     } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG,"I/O Error: "+e.getMessage());
        retv = -2;     // error
     }
  } else {
      // Permission is missing and must be requested.
      requestWriteExternalStoragePermission();
  }
```

Comment: You cannot read or write to arbitrary locations on removable storage using filesystem APIs, regardless of permissions.

Comment: you must implement [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) before you try to read/write external storage. Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23) or later

Comment: onRequestPermissionsResult(), requestPermissions() are in place. On click of button the code attached is called, i.e. just before the file operations by checking for permission using checkSelfPermission(....) and it returns PERMISSION_GRANTED too but the FileOutputStream(...) fails.